# How to ignore lorem ipsum text from spell checker in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, spell-checking, emmet, lorem-ipsum

I'm using Lorem ipsum dummy text in the development stage of my React + Redux web app, but the spell checker is making a ton of distracting underlines under the dummy text and  its pretty distracting and irritating to look at while I'm working.

Does anyone know where I can get a .dic file for this or a setting I can turn off for the Lorem Ipsum text only? I don't really want to go through each lorem ipsum  word and tell the spell checker its correct...

Comment: IDE does not have a solution for this yet (no dictionary): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-571 . Google says Hunspell dictionaries are available for Latin -- may work: https://www.google.com/search?q=hunspell+latin+dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment the IDE does not come with this feature. However, please consider the following options to navigate around the issue instead.

You could opt to install a Hunspell dictionary. Please be aware though that lorem ipsum is not valid Latin as it contains many words which don't exist in Latin, so you will need a special lorem ipsum dictionary.

As a last resort option you could disable this inspection or make the highlighting less severe. To do so go to `Editor > Inspections > Proofreading > Type`. Of course this is a very drastic solution since you would loose *all* your spelling error checks, so probably not something you would want.

If you are interested into when and if this feature will be available, you could follow this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243288